# O que acontece se esqueço um debugger

Tags: javascript, java, c#

Tenho uma dúvida, quando faço depurações as vezes eu me esqueço de tirar o ponto de interrupção, mas o que acontece se eu esquecer e o meu projeto for para produção? Penso eu que como são pontos de interrupção da `ide` nada irá acontecer, mas e se por exemplo na linguagem `javascript` que coloco o `debugger;` em código mesmo, quando o cliente estiver usando algo acontecerá? ou vai continuar a execução normal do programa ?

Comment: codigo de produção deveria ir sem opção de debug, uma versão de release, então não deve afetar em nada, além do mais, *breakpoints* são coisasa da IDE e não vão no código compilado, então não se preocupe com eles.
agora escrever um comando de debugger e mandar no código já é um erro grave, isso não deveria ir  pra produção nunca

Comment: em `c#` você pode usar a diretiva `#if DEBUG`, que vai executar algo somente se estiver executnado em debug, em `java` eu desconheço, mas mandar um `debugger` no `javascript` é um problema

Comment: Ah sim, só queria tirar essa dúvida mesmo, as vezes utilizo o debugger, mas sempre retiro depois, obrigado

Comment: eu tb já deixei um debugger lá, essa é da série "quem nunca" :-D

Comment: Kkkkk eu por enquanto nunca, comecei a pouco tempo, e espero nunca deixar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o cliente, durante o uso será transparente a menos que ele acesse a Ferramente de Desenvolvimento do navegador durante o carregamento da tela.

Neste caso, a execução será pausada a cada `debugger;` que houver, mas nada além disso.

No meu atual cenário já precisei publicar a aplicação com `debugger;` (javascript) pois o problema ocorria somente em uma máquina específica. O `debugger;` está lá até hoje :)

Comment: Lembrando que isso depende de navegador pra navegador. Realmente, no Chrome o debugger só é chamado quando o DevTools está aberto.

Comment: Mas no caso, só uma pessoa está usando a página ou várias?

Comment: Vária pessoas utilizam simultaneamente.

Comment: @vnbrs interessante, não sabia. Poderia dar um exemplo do navegador que pausa mesmo fora do DevTools? Assim já testo minha aplicação tb.